# Saving an huge matrix in .txt file messes up line breaks

Tags: java, matrix, save, text-files

I am saving a 3500 x 2000 matrix via an PrintWriter.

```
    float[][] nodeSH = new float[3500][2000];
    String fullPath = path + name + ".txt";
    File file = new File(fullPath);

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fullPath);
        int sizeX = nodeSH.length;
        int sizeY = nodeSH[0].length;
        out.println(sizeX + "," + sizeY);
        String output = "";

        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
            output = "";
            for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
                output = output + nodeSH[x][y] + ",";
            }
            output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 1);
            out.println(output);

        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It works fine just when I open the text file every 9th line is a little bit shorter than the others.

- I tried to run the same with BufferedWriter as well
- The matrix is always filled
- Even saving a small matrix leads to the same problem

e.g see my: [Textfile Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZRl6.png)

Comment: Nothing wrong with your output.  Your text editor wraps lines to fit them on the screen.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks for the quick responde. Is there a way to block that behavior?

Comment: Use something like Notepad++.